# SSH not working after setting `require-encryption` in Vino to false

Tags: ssh

After I use this command in Ubuntu, I can't access my server with ssh! How can I solve this problem?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

Comment: SSH not working after changing that is a different issue.  That will only affect VNC, what you've changed.  We'd need more information to deduce what's going on; are you using VNC (equivalent of Remote Desktop) or SSH (command-line only administration access)?